# Why std::vector::at() needs bounds checking even with optimizations turned on?

Tags: c++, windows, optimization, dll, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a problem with the `libstdc++-6.dll` in windows. This code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main(){
    std::vector<int> x(10);
    std::cout << x.at(3) << std::endl;
}
```

compiles fine, but when I run it I get a error message saying

> The procedure entry point _ZSt24__throw_out_of_range_fmtPKcz could not be located in the dll libstdc++-6.dll

My question is **not** how to fix this (it is most likely the wrong version of the dll and I just have to fix the PATH). However, this made me realize something quite unexpected:

The above code runs well (regardless of the wrong dll), when I turn on optimizations, ie

```
g++ error.cxx -O2
```

but this code

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

double Foo(const std::vector<int>& x,int index) {    
    int m = x.at(index + 1) - x.at(index);
    int b = x.at(index);
    return b/(m*1.0);
}        
int main(){}
```

does not.

Why do I get the above mentioned error with the second code no matter if I compile it via

```
g++ error.cxx -O2     or       g++ error.cxx
```

?

Again, I know why the error appears, but I would expect that with optimizations turned on, both version do not cause the error. Instead the first version works fine while the second does not. Shouldn't `-O2` completely eliminate bounds checking?

Comment: Because the C++ specification *says* that `at` has to do bounds-checking?

Comment: Because you have `operator[]` for unchecked.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude but then why does the first code work with `-O2` ? Shouldnt both codes produce the error ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The C++ standard *requires* bounds checking for `at()` and the actual implementation code for `at()` does contain the bounds checking.

In your first case however, the bounds are hardcoded (10 elements vs. index 3) and "everything" gets inlined with `-O2`, so the optimizer of the *compiler* removes the code for the bounds-check violation, because it can prove at compile time that the bounds are not violated and the code path not taken (as-if rule).

Therefore, you don't get a *linker* error with `-O2` in that case, because the compiler simply didn't emit the call instruction at all.

---

> Shouldn't -O2 completely eliminate bounds checking?

No, the optimizer has to keep to [the AS-IF rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if), that is, iff the optimizer can prove, at compile time, that a code path is not taken, it can eliminate that code. It doesn't just willy-nilly remove checks that were introduced in the source code.

As a side note, for `vector::operator[]` that *doesn't* require bounds checking, an implementation could (reasonably or not) introduce debug bounds checking, when e.g. `NDEBUG` is not defined, and only do no checking when `NDEBUG` is defined. In that case however, the bounds check would be "removed by the preprocessor" if you will, and not by the optimizer.

Comment: for some reason I had the misconception that bounds checking is only done for debug builds. If this is not the case, the behavior I get makes completely sense

Answer (score 2):

The C++ standard requires `std::vector::at` to be bound-checked:

> 23.2.3 Sequence containers
>
> 1. A sequence container organizes a finite set of objects, all of the same type, into a strictly linear arrangement. The library provides four basic kinds of sequence containers: `vector`, ...
>
> ...
>
> 17. The member function `at()` provides bounds-checked access to container elements. `at()` throws `out_of_range` if `n >= a.size()`.

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector::at` is specified to throw an exception if the index is out of bounds. If you do not want bounds checking, use `operator[]`.

```
m.at(index);
m[index]; //change to this
```

Your first example will not throw an exception, because `std::vector<int> x(10);` creates a vector with 10 `int`s of value `0`, not a vector with 1 `int` of value `10`.

```
std::vector<int> x (10); //{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,}
std::vector<int> x {10}; //{10} due to std::initializer_list constructor
```

Comment: so the compiler is allowed to skip the bounds checking in `at` if it can assert that the index is ok?

Comment: @tobi303 if it can do so at compile-time, sure, that's valid by the "as-if" rule.

Comment: `[]` is worse, it will give you segfault without any explanation when it goes out of bounds...

Comment: @Jahid "worse" depends on the situation. Do you think that you might pass a bad index? Then use `at`. Have you already done the necessary sanitisation and want speed? Use `operator[]`.

Comment: yap, `[]` shouldn't be used unless you are **sure** that it will not go out of bounds.

Comment: @Jahid I would rather say `at()` shouldn't be used unless you aren't sure that it could go out of bounds

Comment: @tobi303 : I think that would be very unwise. `at()` at least tells you what happened, but `[]` gives you nothing but a dumb message `sgementation fault`. So, use `[]` when the index exists (for speed), and `at()` when it can go out of range...

Comment: @Jahid well ok the wording was wrong. I actually meant: `at()` shouldn't be used unless the index can possibly go out of bounds. It is basically the same as your statement, but for me it is certain in 99% of the cases, that the index is ok (often also in cases where the compiler cannot figure out that this is true) and then using `at()` would be unnecessarily inefficient